# How to implement semihosting in ARMv7?

Tags: arm

I have a code for ARMv7 and I am trying to display the results in the Terminal window of the code warrior. I went through the literature and found that I have to modify code in ARM C library to do so. I saw the ARM info center documentation and it says that you can use SVC 0x123456 for achieving this. This information it self is not sufficient to proceed I think. If any one have done semihosting for ARMv7. Please advice on the ARM assembly procedures to be followed to do so.

Comment: Does your debugger support semihosting? If so, then it's a case of "whatever that particular debugger says about its particular semihosting protocol". And if not, then the first thing you'll have to do is get one which does...

Comment: What is a semihosting protocol?